# Remove all before specific symbol in string PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

For example i have string `one two three four five` and I want remove all characters before `two` and after four , I know that is function `preg_replace()` but I don't know how to write this expression, I not know what does mean for example '/([a-z])([A-Z])/' please say what is name of this expression in `$pattern` and what they mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you're looking for preg_replace based solution then here it is:

```
$str = 'one two three four five';
var_dump ( preg_replace('#^.*?(two.*?four).*$#i', '$1', $str) );
```

**Expanation:** RegEx used in `preg_replace` first matches text upto your starting text `two` then matches upto your end text `four` and finally replaces it with matched string thus discarding all text before `two` and all text after `four`. Please note `.*?` makes your matching non-greedy. Read more about regex here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

#### OUTPUT

```
string(14) "two three four"
```

Answer (score 1):

preg_replace is a function which takes in [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to do replacements.

You can and should learn about these, as they are very powerful, but they aren't essential for your problem.

You can use `strpos` and `substr` functions

`substr` takes a string that you want to shorten, a start location and a number of characters and returns the shortened string.

`strpos` takes a string that you want to search, and a string that you want to search for and returns the location of the second string in the first.

So you can use them as such:

```
$text = "one two three four five";
$locationOfTwo = strpos($text, "two"); //The location in the string of the substring "two" (in this case it's 4)
$locationOfFour =strpos($text, "four") + strlen("four"); //Added the length of the word to get to the end of it (In this case it will set the variable to 18).
$subString = subsstr($text, locationOfTwo, (locationOfFour-locationOfTwo));
```